# Why isn't Selenium chromedriver adding a profile?

Tags: python, selenium, debugging, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to add a chrome profile into my program, but it is not doing anything. Can someone please help?

I am using Selenium python. When I run it seems to ignore the statements and runs in a temp profile.

```html
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import random
import string
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

while True:

        emailstarter = random.randint(11111111111111111111,999999999999999999999)
        first = random.randint(666666,888888)
        last = random.randint(555,55555)

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the order wrong. You should create the options first and then pass them as an argument to the `webdriver.Chrome` class:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default");
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe",
        options=options
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, it loaded the profile, but now it doesn't actually run the test, it only opens a new window. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry "``doesn't actually run the test``" is very vague. Feel free to open a new issue with more details, the (minimal) code to reproduce the problem and any error message(s) you're getting with your current code.